# error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt in node js

Tags: node.js, rsa, cryptojs

I'm getting the error in the title, I've looked for it online and found out it was because of auto padding, however, I don't see any auto padding setting in generateKeyPairSync or private decrypt.
How do I deal with it?

```
this.keyPair = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', { 
  modulusLength: 4096, 
  e: 0x010001, 
  publicKeyEncoding: { 
    type: 'spki', 
    format: 'pem', 
  }, 
  privateKeyEncoding: { 
    type: 'pkcs1', 
    format: 'pem', 
    cipher: 'aes-256-cbc', 
    passphrase: 'top secret' 
  } 
})
```

And later on:

```
return crypto.privateDecrypt({ 
  oaepHash: 'sha256', 
  padding: 4, 
  key: this.keyPair.privateKey 
}, Buffer.from(payload, 'base64'))
```

Comment: To better help you, it would be great if you could give us some code to look at.

Comment: Sure.

```this.keyPair = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
      modulusLength: 4096,
      e: 0x010001,
      publicKeyEncoding: {
        type: 'spki',
        format: 'pem',

      },
      privateKeyEncoding: {
        type: 'pkcs1',
        format: 'pem',
        cipher: 'aes-256-cbc',
        passphrase: 'top secret'
      }
    })```
And later on,
```return crypto.privateDecrypt({
      oaepHash: 'sha256',
      padding: 4,
      key: this.keyPair.privateKey
    }, Buffer.from(payload, 'base64'))```